# Idle terminal safe character

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, vim

I'm using iTerm2 on a Mac to do Linux work.  In order to avoid losing terminal connections, I turned on "When idle, sent Ascii code". The default is 0.  This works like a charm to keep connections alive, but there is a serious problem.

This turns out to be sending ^@ to the terminal, which is OK most of the time, but in `vi` it will insert recently entered text.

What can I send that's safe?

Answer (score 9):

Can you not use this `ssh` option instead to keep the connections from disconnecting?

Try this option in your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
ServerAliveInterval=15
```

*excerpt from `man ssh_config`*

```
ServerAliveInterval
      Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been 
      received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the encrypted
      channel to request a response from the server.  The default is 0, 
      indicating that these messages will not be sent to the server.  This 
      option applies to protocol version 2 only.
```

You can do this temporarily from the command line using this switch to `ssh`:

```
$ ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=15 keepsdroppingme.com
```

The permissions of the directory `~/.ssh/` can be a bit troublesome, consult this article if you need any additional guidance: [Prevent your SSH connection from freezing](http://shapeshed.com/prevent_your_ssh_connection_from_freezing/).